# Is it possible to identify all network interfaces with WebRTC on a machine?

Tags: virtual-machine

Does anybody has a machine with two network interfaces or with installed virtual machine? I need to check how WebRTC works in case if a machine has two interfaces, physical or virtual, does not matter. If anybody has, could you, please, look here https://diafygi.github.io/webrtc-ips/ Will the servise identify only one interface or both?

Thanks for an answer in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like it picks up everything

It got

- 4 private IPs (on 4 different network cards)
- 1 public IP v4 address
- 2 Public IP v6 addresses